# List Alfresco folders and documents in BonitaSoft

Tags: alfresco, bonita

I'm working with version 7.6.3 of BonitSoft and intend to integrate with Alfresco version 5.2, and checked that the cmis List a folder connector no longer exists. How can I inject this list into a widget?

Comment: The CMIS "List documents" does not provide the result you need? If something is missing can you clarify what it is? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Alfresco connector provided out-of-the-box in v5 won't be able to list the content of an Alfresco repo. They can only access Alfresco resources using their full path.

You would need to develop a custom connector to do so.

Please refer these questions for more information.

[Bonita BPM list files and move folders in Alfresco](https://community.bonitasoft.com/questions-and-answers/bonita-bpm-list-files-and-move-folders-alfresco)

https://documentation.bonitasoft.com/6.x-7.2/creating-connector

[Bonita integration with Alfresco](https://community.bonitasoft.com/questions-and-answers/bonita-integration-alfresco)